# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'

Tags: php, wordpress, синтаксис

Есть сайт на `wordpress` последней версии с `php7` на хостинге с минимизированным файлом `style_dynamic.php` в теме.
В изначальном варианте в консоли имею ошибку 500 от сервера - в логах вот что:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$root' (T_VARIABLE) in

добавляю пробел в строчку - ошибка исчезает

```
<?php$root...
```

теперь уже горит

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in

Эту уже не знаю как устранить, то если преобразую к полному виду [с помощью сервиса](http://beta.phpformatter.com/) и добавляю в проект, то ошибка исчезает. 
Где кроется ошибка минификации и с чем это связано и почему возникает - новые жесткие требования `php7` ?

Comment: там же явно написано - "Formatter BETA" и "php4 & 5".

Comment: А на полный оригинальный код можно глянуть?

Comment: @E_p - да https://jsfiddle.net/22mcpkgm/